# BATCH Cannot use a variable with comma or semicolon when using call

Tags: batch-file

So i got a batch file that creates a random pass(code). But when the pass has a comma or semicolon it just execute(using call) until the comma or semicolon.

For example i have fgafsasdfsafd,asdasdasd as a result. When i use that result with call the %1 is just fgagsasdfsafd. Any suggestions?

I use randomcahars.
Generations Code Is:

```
randomchars 25 /s
```

Link to the code:
https://hastebin.com/refufuxopi.erl

If nothing cannot fix this, i can delete "," and ";" from specialchar list in the code.

I just noticed that / can make the same result.

Comment: Please post your code here.  Many people cannot access external sites.  That is defined in the faq for StackOverFlow.  You can always pass command line arguments to a batch file or a CALL to a label by enclosing them in quotes. `CALL :label "fgafsasdfsafd,asdasdasd"` or `CALL myscript.bat "fgafsasdfsafd,asdasdasd"`

Comment: Btw quotes didn't worked for me i already tested i don'n know why.

Comment: @barışsedefoğlu, **The provided script has a copyright notice**, from somebody with a different name. Unless you can show that you are that person or have authority to alter their code, it would not be proper or correct for us to help you with any modification(s). **I have therefore deleted the code, because I have no idea if this site has authority to display it.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the proven code creator / copyright holder has not given express consent for the code to be displayed here or modified.

Comment: @Squashman, they aren't their `Set` commands, nor have they shown that they have express permission to modify them! If they wish for modifications to that code they should contact Jason Faulkner _(mailto:me@jasonfaulkner.com)_ themselves and ask.

Comment: @Compo, the code is freely available from Jason's website.  In my opinion this makes it public domain.

Comment: @Squashman, It's available to download in an archive file and clearly displays a copyright notification. I cannot see the code content visible on his site, can you provide a link to it?

Comment: @Compo, seriously.  Now you are just being stubborn and arguing semantics. From Jason's website: **I provide all my tools free of charge with fairly permissive terms and conditions for use.**

Comment: @Squashman, they aren't semantics, the rights are reserved, so without Jason's permission or an explanation of what if anything can be modified or displayed here we cannot be seen to be party to potential breaches of that copyright. I see no reason why, given that his contact information is available that it wouldn't be prudent to get those permissions first.

Comment: @Compo, define permissive.

Comment: @Squashman, are you saying that adhering to a copyright notice is not obligatory, _(optional)_? Asking Jason, to define his meaning of permissive would be the correct procedure, not I. The conditions for use are not defined there so without his definition we are in the dark.

Comment: @barışsedefoğlu, you need to show us how you are using the Jason's code and how you are using the output from Jason's code.  We do not need to see Jason's code at all.

Comment: @barışsedefoğlu, from Jason's website, **I have a vested interest in making sure it works as well as possible.** It would be morally correct and courteous if there are problems with, or potential improvements to, his code to contact him about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the third party script you are using. Essentially your problem is you are not understanding how to use the result of output when it has special characters. To protect the special characters in a variable you normally surround them in quotes.

So here is a short example that proves surrounding the data in quotes works.

```
@echo off
CALL :label fgafsasdfsafd,asdasd;asd
CALL :label "fgafsasdfsafd,asdasd;asd"
pause
goto :EOF

:label
echo %~1
```

And the output of that is:

```
C:\Users\Squashman\Desktop>so.bat
fgafsasdfsafd
fgafsasdfsafd,asdasd;asd
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So just to prove that there is nothing wrong with [Jason's Random Character batch file](http://jasonfaulkner.com/RandomChars.aspx) I purposely changed the special characters variable to only use a comma and semicolon.

```
SET SpecialCharList=,;
SET SpecialCharListLength=2
```

Now we will run his script using this code.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('CALL RandomChars 25 /S') DO CALL :label "%%G"

goto :EOF
:label
echo %~1
```

The output shows that the comma and semi-colon are just fine when you quote the argument.

```
Y:\>so.bat
25Ahxb0zVY5l1Hx8B,DKZuCCG

Y:\>so.bat
Yab7Ux5tr7eg850UhPBfCq,vi

Y:\>so.bat
P20Tt0se7k5aIIDm16etZ,ZkM

Y:\>so.bat
Z2PpjwgFj8Z6aBMe,LI4Bcygg

Y:\>so.bat
f0d0F9AGj;wEwci7gEKrkNwa5
```

Comment: i have 1 more quertion. When i use quotes it crashes when the command is at the call. I am not using the for loop i am using it with %output% as the output of the script. Code: call :therestofthecode "%output%"  //and it crashes any help for that?